# listview objects are not redirecting to detailview when clicked

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a blog , i am able to display list of objects in my blog model by class based list view.. but when trying to display them individually by function based detail view i am getting 404 error.

(The current path, blog/1, didn't match any of these.)

i tried class based views as well but unfortunately got no success.. please see..

models.py

```
         from django.db import models
         import datetime
        # Create your models here.
      
class BlogPost(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
writer = models.CharField(max_length=150,default='my dept')
category =models.CharField(max_length=150)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
post   = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
Date  = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)


def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views.py

```
    from django.views.generic import ListView , DetailView , UpdateView
    from.models import BlogPost

class BlogList(ListView):
model = BlogPost
template_name = 'blog/bloglist.html'
context_object_name = 'post'
```

def detailview(request, id=None):
blg = get_object_or_404(BlogPost, id=id)

```
context = {'blg': blg,
           }

return render(request, 'blog/blogdetail.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
   from django.urls import path

       # importing views from views..py 
     from .views import  BlogList ,detailview

urlpatterns = [
path('list', BlogList.as_view(), name='list'),
path('(?P<id>\d+)/$', detailview, name='detail')

         ]
```

bloglist.html

```
                    <div class="post-body">
                        {% for p in posts %}
                        <a href="/blog/{{ p.id }}"><blockquote>{{p}}</br></br>{{p.Date}}</blockquote> 
                           </a>

                        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the *wrong syntax* for `path(...)` function. It should be as

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogList, detailview

urlpatterns = [
    path('list', BlogList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('<int:pk>/', detailview, name='detail')
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

]
```